# jquery.mobile-1.0rc1 and themes

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I update my apps to the latest release of jquery,mobile-1.0rc1  All my set data themes go to the black default. Even when I explicitly code `data-theme="b"` etc.  Did I miss something?

Comment: OK I see themes are now added to the element div you want them for and no longer will adding them to the page div.

Answer (score 0):

OK I see themes are now added to the element div you want them for and no longer will adding them to the page div work.